# iframe target in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I have a problem about a tag in Asp.NET page. Here is the code.

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#" class="selected">Ana Sayfa</a></li>
<li><a href="Yerleske.aspx" target="myFrame">Yerleşke</a></li>
</ul>

<iframe runat="server" id="myFrame" width="1120"  height="750" class="iframescrolling">      
</iframe>
```

I want to display Yerleske.aspx page into the iframe. They are on the same page. There is an attribute like multiview in Asp.Net but I could not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **scr** and set **ClientIDMode** to Static so your link will work.

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#" class="selected">Ana Sayfa</a></li>
<li><a href="Yerleske.aspx" target="myFrame">Yerleşke</a></li>
</ul>

<iframe src="erleske.aspx" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" id="myFrame" width="1120"  height="750" class="iframescrolling" >      
</iframe>
```

Comment: I do not have only one page, there are another pages instead of yerleske.aspx. How can I add src to other pages.

Comment: What do you mean to other pages ?
Add more Iframes...  or more links with target="myFrame"
Please explain your question?